# SIP Servlet not starting in JBOSS 7.2 from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jboss, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I currently work on a project based on Mobicents SIP Servlets and JBoss 7.2. I created a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with the template the Mobicents Eclipse Plugin gives me, then mavenize it. Then I created a JBoss Server in Eclipse pointing to my Mobicents Jboss installation. When I deploy my servlet now, I see the exploded war in the Jboss installation and the logs say that it is deployed, but I do not see that it logged anything.

My very basic servlet:

```
package org.example.servlet.sip;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MySipServlet extends SipServlet {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MySipServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        logger.info("the HelloSipWorld servlet has been started");      
    }

}
```

Log:

```
12:54:12,102 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.CR1
12:54:12,315 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA
12:54:12,378 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" starting
12:54:13,392 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found test-as.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called test-as.war.dodeploy
12:54:13,426 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
12:54:13,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
12:54:13,435 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
12:54:13,453 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.14.GA
12:54:13,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:54:13,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:54:13,570 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
12:54:13,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
12:54:13,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:54:13,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.15.Final
12:54:13,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.15.Final)
12:54:13,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
12:54:13,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:54:13,777 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:54:13,958 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.1.3.Final
12:54:14,080 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
12:54:14,093 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
12:54:14,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:54:14,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
12:54:14,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
12:54:14,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/jck/Desktop/ngncc/as/mobicents/mss-2.1.547-jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments
12:54:14,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "media-jsr309-servlet.war" (runtime-name: "media-jsr309-servlet.war")
12:54:14,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "test-as.war" (runtime-name: "test-as.war")
12:54:14,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "click2call.war" (runtime-name: "click2call.war")
12:54:14,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jolokia.war" (runtime-name: "jolokia.war")
12:54:14,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sip-servlets-management.war" (runtime-name: "sip-servlets-management.war")
12:54:14,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "websockets-sip-servlet.war" (runtime-name: "websockets-sip-servlet.war")
12:54:15,139 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBAS018210: Register web context: /test-as
12:54:15,140 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS018210: Register web context: /websockets-sip-servlet
12:54:15,143 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS018210: Register web context: /jolokia
12:54:15,145 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS018210: Register web context: /sip-servlets-management
12:54:15,373 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jolokia]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed
12:54:15,754 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS018210: Register web context: /media-jsr309-servlet
12:54:16,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "sip-servlets-management.war" (runtime-name : "sip-servlets-management.war")
12:54:16,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "test-as.war" (runtime-name : "test-as.war")
12:54:16,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "jolokia.war" (runtime-name : "jolokia.war")
12:54:16,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "websockets-sip-servlet.war" (runtime-name : "websockets-sip-servlet.war")
12:54:16,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "click2call.war" (runtime-name : "click2call.war")
12:54:16,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "media-jsr309-servlet.war" (runtime-name : "media-jsr309-servlet.war")
12:54:16,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.security.security-domain.sip-servlets (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./click2call.realm] 

12:54:16,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:54:16,119 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:54:16,119 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" started (with errors) in 4413ms - Started 368 of 443 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 71 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Any hints on what I am doing wrong is highly appreciated. I use SIP Servlets 2.1.547 on JBoss 7.2.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you select standalone-sip.xml as profile in the configuration. SIP Servlets Container uses a specific configuration which is not the default I believe when you start through Eclipse

Comment: I changed the RuntimeConfiguration of the server to -mp "/home/jck/Desktop/ngncc/as/mobicents/mss-2.1.547-jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone-sip.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/jck/Desktop/ngncc/as/mobicents/mss-2.1.547-jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone  , but I still get the same result

Comment: I removed everything related to that Eclipse and mobicents, then started totally from scratch. While creating a new server instance, I found that you can select the standalone-sip.xml in the creation process. I missed that the last time. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your servlet with @SipServlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@javax.servlet.sip.annotation.SipServlet
public class MySipServlet extends SipServlet {
```

Add sip dependencies like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>sip-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure maven dependencies are present in WEB-INF/lib. If not, go to
Your Project> Properties > Deployment Assembly > Click Add.. and select "Build Path entries", then select "Maven dependencies".

Also you have error in your log, so you are definitely missing some dependencies:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.security.security-domain.sip-servlets (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./click2call.realm]
```

Comment: I removed click2call from the JBoss (it comes by default, I have nothing to do with it). The dependencies are all met, everything builds cleanly, so that is also not the reason.

Comment: what about the @SipServlet

Comment: That also did not change stuff.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you add the following category in the \server\default\conf\jboss-log4j.xml

   ```
   <category name="org.example.servlet">
     <priority value="INFO"/></category>
   ```
2. If you do not intend to test click2call use-case why not remove the war from your jboss's deploy folder.

Comment: I removed click2call (it comes by default, and after some reinstallations of the JBoss, I did not bother anymore). I did not find a "jboss-log4j.xml" in my installation.

Comment: I have worked with JBoss 5 and using jboss-log4j.xml I used to customize logging. I think in Joss 7 you can control this through standalone.xml      Please look and add the following there:       <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
...
        <logger category="org.example.servlet">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
...